# ¿Cómo sumar varias columnas y determinar el porcentaje que corresponde a cada valor de la columna respecto al total general?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Tengo la siguiente tabla con la cantidad de viviendas según su clase y el total, para diferentes sitios.

```
CREATE TABLE viviendas
(id_cp int,
sitio varchar(30), 
clase_a int,
clase_b int,
clase_c int,
clase_d int,
clase_e int,
clase_f int,
viviendas_cp int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (clase_a + clase_b + clase_c + clase_d + clase_e + clase_f) STORED
);
```

Deseo crear una vista donde me muestre los mismos datos que la tabla y además los porcentajes con respecto al total de viviendas (suma de las viviendas de todos los sitios). Utilizando lo que aparece debajo arroja el error:

> la columna «viviendas.id_cp» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación

```
CREATE VIEW vista_viviendas
AS
 SELECT id_cp,
         sitio,
         clase_a, 
         ROUND(clase_a::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_a",
         clase_b, 
         ROUND(clase_b::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_b",
         clase_c,
         ROUND(clase_c::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_c",
         clase_d,
         ROUND(clase_d::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_d",
         clase_e,
         ROUND(clase_e::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_e",
         clase_f,
         ROUND(clase_f::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_f"
    FROM viviendas
;
```

OK...., coloqué id_cp dentro de un GROUP BY.
Pero ahora me arroja el mismo mensaje para la siguiente columna (sitio). También la agregué al GROUP BY y vuelve a aparecer un mensaje igual para la siguiente columna.
Solo después de agregar al GROUP BY todas las columnas que aparecen en el SELECT es que se ejecutó sin error...

```
Create VIEW vista_viviendas
AS
 SELECT id_cp,
         sitio,
         clase_a, 
         ROUND(clase_a::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_a",
         clase_b, 
         ROUND(clase_b::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_b",
         clase_c,
         ROUND(clase_c::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_c",
         clase_d,
         ROUND(clase_d::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_d",
         clase_e,
         ROUND(clase_e::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_e",
         clase_f,
         ROUND(clase_f::numeric*100/SUM(viviendas_cp),2) as "%_clase_f"
    FROM viviendas
GROUP BY id_cp, sitio, clase_a, clase_b, clase_c, clase_d, clase_e, clase_f
ORDER BY id_cp
;
```

Pero en verdad el resultado no es el que esperaba, los porcentajes que da son respecto al total de viviendas en un sitio, no respecto al total de viviendas que aparecen en la tabla.
Por ejemplo, insertando los siguientes datos el porcentaje que arroja es 16.67, pero 1*100/60 es 1.67

```
insert into viviendas (id_cp,sitio,clase_a,clase_b,clase_c,clase_d,clase_e,clase_f)
values 
(1,'sitio1',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(2,'sitio2',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(3,'sitio3',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(4,'sitio4',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(5,'sitio5',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(6,'sitio6',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(7,'sitio7',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(8,'sitio8',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(9,'sitio9',1,1,1,1,1,1),
(10,'sitio10',1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

Parece que no se puede utilizar SUM() sin utilizar GROUP BY, pero al hacerlo me da un resultado que no espero.
Alguna sugerencia para solucionar el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en tu tabla tuvieses

| id_cp | sitio | clase_a | clase_b | clase_c | clase_d | clase_e | clase_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sitio1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | sitio1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | sitio2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

querrías que el porcentaje fuese relativo al total del sitio? En ese caso para el sitio 1 todos los porcentajes serían 1/12, y para el sitio 2 todos serían 1/6.

querrías en cambio ver el porcentaje con respecto a todos los sitios? En ese caso serían 1/18 para todos.

Se pueden repetir los sitios? En ese caso querrías mostrar un solo registro por sitio?

En todos los casos yo precalcularía el total usando un bloque `WITH` , y si además es necesario presentar un registro por sitio, también precalcularía esa agrupación.

Vamos a decir, para simplificar, que tu tabla tiene 3 clases, y la lleno con los siguientes datos

```
insert into viviendas (id_cp,sitio,clase_a,clase_b,clase_c )
values          
(1,'sitio1',1,1,1),
(2,'sitio2',1,1,1),
(3,'sitio1',1,1,1),
(4,'sitio2',1,1,1),
(5,'sitio3',1,1,1),
(6,'sitio4',1,1,1),
(7,'sitio5',1,1,1),
(8,'sitio5',1,1,1),
(9,'sitio5',1,1,1),
(10,'sitio6',1,1,1);



SELECT * from viviendas;
```

| id_cp | sitio | clase_a | clase_b | clase_c | viviendas_cp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sitio1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | sitio2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | sitio1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | sitio2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | sitio3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | sitio4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | sitio5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | sitio5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | sitio5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | sitio6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

---

(nótese que se repiten sitios). La salida de la query

```
WITH total_por_sitio AS (
        SELECT   sitio,
            SUM(clase_a) as clase_a, 
            SUM(clase_b) as clase_b, 
            SUM(clase_c) as clase_c,
           
            sum(viviendas_cp) as total_parcial
        FROM viviendas GROUP BY sitio
     ),
     total_global AS (
        select sum(viviendas_cp) as gran_total FROM viviendas
     )
        
     SELECT sitio,
     clase_a, 
         ROUND(clase_a::numeric*100/total_parcial,2) as "%a_sitio",
         ROUND(clase_a::numeric*100/gran_total,2) as "%a_global",
         clase_b, 
         ROUND(clase_b::numeric*100/total_parcial,2) as "%b_sitio",
         ROUND(clase_b::numeric*100/gran_total,2) as "%b_global",
         clase_c,
         ROUND(clase_c::numeric*100/total_parcial,2) as "%c_sitio",
         ROUND(clase_c::numeric*100/gran_total,2) as "%c_global"
         
           
     FROM total_por_sitio
         JOIN total_global ON 1=1;
```

mostrará:

| sitio | clase_a | %a_sitio | %a_global | clase_b | %b_sitio | %b_global | clase_c | %c_sitio | %c_global |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sitio6 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 |
| sitio5 | 3 | 33.33 | 10.00 | 3 | 33.33 | 10.00 | 3 | 33.33 | 10.00 |
| sitio1 | 2 | 33.33 | 6.67 | 2 | 33.33 | 6.67 | 2 | 33.33 | 6.67 |
| sitio3 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 |
| sitio2 | 2 | 33.33 | 6.67 | 2 | 33.33 | 6.67 | 2 | 33.33 | 6.67 |
| sitio4 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 | 1 | 33.33 | 3.33 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbmAysuhVi3buMWSdRbhfp/4)

Answer (score 0):

Llevaba varios días buscando una respuesta, hoy en [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067133/postgresql-determining-the-percentage-of-a-total) encontré esta sugerencia de @Andomar para sumar una columna usando SUM() sin utilizar GROUP BY:

```
SELECT  100.0 * number / sum(number) over () as perc
FROM    mytable;
```

Ya que la suma de los subtotales de las columnas es igual que la suma de los subtotales de las filas, modifiqué el código de esta forma y funcionó correctamente:

```
Create VIEW vista_viviendas
AS
 SELECT id_cp,
         sitio,
         clase_a, 
         ROUND(clase_a::numeric*100/(SUM(clase_a) over () +SUM(clase_b) over () +SUM(clase_c) over () + SUM(clase_d) over () +SUM(clase_e) over () + SUM(clase_f) over ()),2) as "%_clase_a",
         clase_b, 
         ROUND(clase_b::numeric*100/(SUM(clase_a) over () +SUM(clase_b) over () +SUM(clase_c) over () + SUM(clase_d) over () +SUM(clase_e) over () + SUM(clase_f) over ()),2) as "%_clase_b",
         clase_c,
         ROUND(clase_c::numeric*100/(SUM(clase_a) over () +SUM(clase_b) over () +SUM(clase_c) over () + SUM(clase_d) over () +SUM(clase_e) over () + SUM(clase_f) over ()),2) as "%_clase_c",
         clase_d,
         ROUND(clase_d::numeric*100/(SUM(clase_a) over () +SUM(clase_b) over () +SUM(clase_c) over () + SUM(clase_d) over () +SUM(clase_e) over () + SUM(clase_f) over ()),2) as "%_clase_d",
         clase_e,
         ROUND(clase_e::numeric*100/(SUM(clase_a) over () +SUM(clase_b) over () +SUM(clase_c) over () + SUM(clase_d) over () +SUM(clase_e) over () + SUM(clase_f) over ()),2) as "%_clase_e",
         clase_f,
         ROUND(clase_f::numeric*100/(SUM(clase_a) over () +SUM(clase_b) over () +SUM(clase_c) over () + SUM(clase_d) over () +SUM(clase_e) over () + SUM(clase_f) over ()),2) as "%_clase_f"
    FROM viviendas
;
```

Sin embargo, quizás exista una forma más elegante y eficiente para obtener el mismo resultado.